# Why storing result of getSignedUrl in database is bad idea?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have started to work on existing project where result of `getSignedUrl` plus expiration time are being persisted in database. My intuition tells me that this is bad and wrong but I can't provide clear explanation why and what is better alternative? One of the factors why I think this approach is bad is that it requires data modification on read only data queries(ie if url has expired it has to be updated in database). Another reason - this feels for me like storage of computed value which is not even that expensive to compute and in case this have to be optimized I guess there should be additional cache mechanism which handles this instead of database. Is my reasoning correct? How can I provide better explanation to my colleagues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will really depend on the usecase as to why its being stored in the database, however as you point out it is adding extra latency for the user as presumably you would be querying the database or retrieving from the cache static images.

Whilst signed URLs can be re-used and there is nothing wrong with this, if every asset is using its own signed URL this will add to the maintenance of the application. There are two approaches that could do this:

- A scripted action constantly recycling through assets to repopulate the data store of signed URLs.
- Writing to the database to retrieve in the user workflow if the link has expired.

Needless to say none of these are ideal, if this is primarily frontend assets I would recommend looking at whether you can add CloudFront in front of your origin and make use of [signed cookies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-cookies.html) instead.

This provides similar functionality to a signed URL, but instead have the application generate a cookie for the user that will then grant the user access to the assets without needing to either generate a new signed URL every time or look up in a database. Both of those options add to the user performance and experience.

If the signed URLs are for reports or generated content, I believe these should be generated when a user requests it (although this is my opinion). This will make it easier to look back through any auditing to determine when the action was required and will need a user to authenticate again once the URL has expired.

Also consider if the signed URL resolves to sensitive content and it is stored plainly in a database that your developers have access to, then they would be able to retrieve this information.